# Canopy clustering implementation in Python

Tags: python, clustering

As far as I understand, canopy clustering preprocessing procedure is not implemented in scikit-learn.

Is there a python library for this?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/bread-tan/canopyClusteringPython)'s a Hadoop-based python implementation (not tested).

Comment: You should email the very nice scikit-learn mailing list.

Comment: You can find an implementation [here](https://gist.github.com/gdbassett/528d816d035f2deaaca1).